# How can I add custom header parameters to a API GET call in clojurescript

Tags: api, http-headers, clojurescript

I'm building a demo application in clojurescript with KeeFrame and to retrieve a part of the information for this website I need to call an external API which requires a custom HTTP header parameter in the GET requests

I'm using re-frame.core for the API calls, which uses ajax.core.
I also tried to replace this with cljs-http.client. However the result is the same.
I already managed to add custom header parameters to the request header by using clj-http at server site. But this is not a solution I want to implement for this website because that means that I first have to rebuild the API I'm calling. So I can use it from my clojurescript without the parameter.

This code works. A correct GET request is generated

```
{:http-xhrio {
 :method          :get
 :uri             (str transuri "/acquirer/" 673072009 "/acquirerref/" acquirerRefNo)
 :headers         {"Accept" "application/json"}
 :response-format (http/json-response-format {:keywords? true})
 :on-failure      [:common/set-error]}}
```

With "Accept: application/json" as a request header

This code does not work. Instead of a GET request an OPTIONS request is generated

```
{:http-xhrio {
 :method          :get
 :uri             (str transuri "/acquirer/" 673072009 "/acquirerref/" acquirerRefNo)
 :headers         {"Accept" "application/json" "Custom" "Value"}
 :response-format (http/json-response-format {:keywords? true})
 :on-failure      [:common/set-error]}}
```

And in the request header "Accept: application/json" is not visible but "Access-Control-Request-Headers: custom" is

I expected a GET request with "Accept: application/json" and "Custom: Value" in the request header.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or provide me with a link with information about this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Browser will send a "preflight" OPTIONS request to verify that it is allowed to send the "Custom" request header. The server is supposed to approve by replying with "Access-Control-Allow-Headers".

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: This was indeed what happened. But due to firewalls the OPTIONS request is not answered from this site and therefore the GET request was never send.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used KeeFrame, but I have a working example using a new `re-frame` lib I'm working on.  It invokes an ajax request using this interceptor:

```
(def ajax-intc
  "Interceptor for performing AJAX requests"
  (interceptor
    {:id    :ajax-intc
     :enter identity
     :leave (fn [ctx] ; #todo (with-result ctx ...)
              (let [ajax (:ajax ctx)]
                ;(t/spyx :ajax-intc-start ctx)
                ;(t/spyx :ajax-intc-start ajax)
                (when-not (nil? ajax)
                  (t/spy :awt-ajax-intc--ajax ajax)
                  (let [method            (t/grab :method ajax)
                        uri               (t/grab :uri ajax)
                        ajax-opts-present (set/intersection (set (keys ajax)) ajax-options-keys)
                        opts-map          (t/submap-by-keys ajax ajax-opts-present)]
                    ;(t/spy :ajax-intc-ready (t/vals->map method uri opts-map))
                    (condp = method
                      :get (do
                             (t/spy :awt-ajax-intc--opts-map opts-map)
                             (ajax/GET uri opts-map))
                      :put (ajax/PUT uri opts-map)
                      :post (ajax/POST uri opts-map)
                      (throw (ex-info "ajax-intc: unrecognized :method" ajax))))))
              ctx)}))
```

When invoked with this event:

```
  (flame/dispatch-event [:ajax-demo :get "/fox.txt"
                         {:handler       ajax-handler
                          :error-handler ajax-error-handler
                          :headers       {"custom" "something"}
                          }])
```

one can see in the Chrome dev console that the headers come through:

```
:awt-localstore-load-intc--loaded-value-1 {}
core.cljs:192 :awt-ajax-intc--ajax => {:method :get, :uri "/fox.txt", :handler #object[flintstones$core$ajax_handler], :error-handler #object[flintstones$core$ajax_error_handler], :headers {"custom" "something"}}
core.cljs:192 :awt-ajax-intc--opts-map => {:handler #object[flintstones$core$ajax_handler], :error-handler #object[flintstones$core$ajax_error_handler], :headers {"custom" "something"}}
```

If you want to try it out, you can clone this repo:     git@github.com:cloojure/cljs-enflame.git

and then run:

```
lein clean
lein figwheel
```

and see it run in the browser.